# javascript: if checkbox checked and textarea empty, alert

Tags: javascript, html

how i can do it? i want alert when the user click on submit button, and this alert must show only if the checkbox is checked and textarea is empty...because this textarea are hidden, and show when checkbox is checked.

ex: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gDttK/

HTML:

```
   <label for="check">other
     <input type="checkbox" name="check0" id="check">
   </label>
   <div id="show">
    <textarea cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
   #show { display: none;}
```

Javascript:

```
$("#check").change(function () {
$("#show").toggle($("#check:checked").length > 0);});
```

Comment: Your fiddle didn't work for me. Changing the jQuery version fixed that: http://jsfiddle.net/gDttK/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an alert and to stop the form from processing. 
To prevent the form processing you use: `event.preventDefault();`.

**Proof:** http://jsfiddle.net/UnWt9/

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <label for="check">other
    <input type="checkbox" name="check0" id="check"></label>
<br>
    <div id="show">
        <textarea cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<br>
        </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
<form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#check").change(function(){
    $("#show").toggle($("#check").prop('checked'));
});

$('form').submit(function(event){

    if( $("#check").prop('checked') && !$.trim($("#show textarea").val()).length ){
           alert('checkbox chcked textarea empty');
        event.preventDefault();
        return;
    }

    event.preventDefault(); // here only for testing
    alert('form submitted');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about your fiddle, but from your question you could do something like this: (you will need to properly adjust your HTML as well)

*updated*

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    if ($("#check").not(":checked") && $('#show textarea').val().length <= 0) { e.preventDefault(); alert('error'); }   
});
```

Comment: Ops! loop! when fill the textarea the alert continues, and the return must be false to not submit form.

Comment: yes, that's what i changed, plus added the prevention of the form being submitted if the attributes are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer.

HTML:

```
<label for="check">other
    <input type="checkbox" name="check0" id="check"></label>
    <div id="show">
        <textarea cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" id="mysubmit">
```

JS:

```
$("#check").change(function(){
    $("#show").toggle($("#check:checked").length > 0);
});

$("#mysubmit").click(function(){
    if($("#check:checked").length > 0){
        alert("Some text");
    }
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/alaminopu/gDttK/2/

Comment: @LeandroRuel add this on the if condition && !$.trim($("#show textarea").val()).length